# VSCode Autocomplete for static Laravel Model Methods

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I can't get VSCode to suggest static methods of my models like "create" or "where". I f i type for example "User::c" Vs code suggests nothing. Also if I enter User::create VSCode doesnt know this method. It's really Annonying to look into the documentation each time I need one of these methods...

```
$user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))
]);
```

Is there maybe an other class, that contains these methods, so I can look it up while developing insead of googleing?

Comment: There is a [vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgykurian.laravel-ide-helper) plugin available that wraps the [Laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) which you might find useful if you're not already using it?